# How to use Nuclide debugger?

Tags: android, react-native, nuclide-editor

I selected Debugger >> Launch/ Attach and "Type" as "React Native" and check "Start Packager".
A "Starting debugger" progress bar opens on a right panel but it hangs after a while and nothing happens.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this instruction](https://nuclide.io/docs/platforms/react-native/) you should:

1. From the [command Palette](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/basics/#command-palette) (Cmd-Shift-P) choose "Nuclide React Native: Start Packager" to start the React Native Server.
2. Ensure that you are in the root directory of the React Native project, then run the application from the command-line: "$ react-native run-ios" (or choose other existing simulator, for example react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone4s").
3. After starting the server, you can prime the React Native Debugger for when the application begins running. From the [command Palette](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/basics/#command-palette) (Cmd-Shift-P), launch "Nuclide React Native: Start Debugging".
4. From the Simulator press Cmd-D (Ctrl-D on Linux). This will bring up the debug options for your application. Select "Debug JS Remotely.

...After you enable debugging from the simulated application, Nuclide will attach to that debugging process automatically, since we primed the Debugger above.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Nuclide debugger iOS project it shows "Starting Debugger" and progress bar opens on a right panel.

then hit ⌘-R in iOS simulator to reload the app, the Nuclide debugger starts work。